# How to connect to a remote Jupyter server from vscode.dev

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

**Question**: How do I get URL for `jupyter server` when jupyter extension is installed in [VSCode for web](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/vscode-web)?

I have successfully installed `python` and `jupyter` extensions on [VSCode for web](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/vscode-web). But when I try to run the simple notebook with code `print('Test')`, it displays the message `Select a kernel to run cells.`. And then it asks for entering URL for jupyter server. It also refers to this [link](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/wiki/Connecting-to-a-remote-Jupyter-server-from-vscode.dev) for more help.

**NOTE**: Readers of this post can simply test the above scenario by just opening https://vscode.dev in `MS Edge` or `Chrome` browsers.

**References**:

- [vscode.dev(!)](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/10/20/vscode-dev)
- [Jupyter Notebooks on the web](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/notebooks-web#:%7E:text=Connect%20to%20a%20remote%20Jupyter%20server,-You%20can%20also&text=To%20do%20so%2C%20select%20the,Select%20Existing.)

Answer (score 0):

The URL is the port of the jupyter server that you want to remotely access.

To get the URL for a Jupyter server, you can use the `jupyter notebook list` command in your terminal.

You can read document about [Connect to a remote Jupyter Server](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks#_connect-to-a-remote-jupyter-server) for more details.